# First Principal Component Large Volatility

Tags: volatility, pca, principal-components

I am conducting PCA on several return series of funds and am finding that when I look at the first principal component the values are huge and this the volatility is also enormous relative to the funds I have used to construct the PCA.

The average return vol for the funds is 3.38% with the largest being roughly 5%. The volatility however for the first PC is 17%, I thought the first PC was most likely a market factor (although with funds instead of stocks I’m not sure). I think the first PC in this instance is most likely a healthcare factor as funds with large loadings in the first PC are heavy on healthcare stocks.

My question therefore is how can the first PC have such a large volatility and what might the first PC represent (not specifically)?

Comment: What % of the returns are explained by the first PC? It doesn't quite make sense that the first PC would be "huge" (i.e. > 70%...?) and it's Vol would be 17%, whilst the average Vol for the funds would be only 3.38%. Otherwise, what time series are you looking at? Does it include the past year (i.e. Covid-induced higher vol?) The healthcare sector stocts have been very volatile over the past year, which could explain the relatively higher vol for the Healthcare sector.

Comment: Ok so I’m not mad that doesn’t really make sense does it! I am using the last three years so includes Covid yep but even so, I compared the returns against the S&P biotech select which is a very volatile biotech index and the returns are still way higher vol wise. 20% explained variance for the first PC

Comment: Note I am using a PCA on the transposed return series meaning the PCs themselves have a value for each date which I am comparing the vol of the PC to the funds

Comment: The key question is: what % of the variance of the returns are explained by your first PC?

Comment: 20% the first PC explains

Comment: If the first PC only explains 20% of the variance of the returns, then your results are *not* that surprising: it could be that the first PC has 17% vol whist the remaining 80% of your PCs only have vol < 3%, which could then in total produce a vol of 3.38%. Also it is a bit odd that the first PC only explains 20% of your data variance: in my experience, the first PC usually explains between at least 50% to over 70% of the total variance in the data...

Comment: I think I’ve worked out what’s wrong, I’ve done the transpose of the return series, so the first principal component is a linear combination of each time point. So PC1 in this instance is the linear combination of each day that gives the maximum variance. I think that plotting PC1 therefore doesn’t necessarily equal the time series for the market or anything like that in fact I think it’s most likely not interpretable?

Comment: Yes, sounds like you found the mistake. You want the PCs to decompose the variance across risk-factors, not across time.

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I were to use clustering for this after PCA I assume I would use the factor loadings therefore?

Comment: And the score which has a value for each date for PC1 would therefore be the time series returns of factor (which could or could not be the market etc)